# Formula keeps changing range when a new row is being added

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple tables with score information , i.e. Name , Score 1, Score 2 ,3 ,etc.

After all the scores i have the following formula on cell L2 : =IFERROR(AVERAGE(D2:K2),"")

The problem is that if I add a new row to the table including a name and Score 1 ,2, 3 , etc. The range on the formula changes automatically to : =IFERROR(AVERAGE(D2:K3),"") and the average will not be accurate because is calculating a result base on 2 rows when is suppose to calculate the range using 1 row

I've been fixing this issue manually after adding all the names and scores by pasting the original formula on cell L2 and dragging down but I would like to know if there is any way that the table can do it automatically without changing the range on the formula ?

Comment: Have you tried *=IFERROR(AVERAGE($D$2:$K$2),"")*

Comment: I've tried and excel always change the range automatically  to $D$2:$K$3 . Before adding a new row the range is D2:K2 on cell L2 but as soon as I add a new row it changes to D2:K3

Answer (score 0):

This should "freeze" the formula range:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDIRECT("D2:K2")),"")
```

because the argument of *INDIRECT()* is not adjustable resulting from changing table limits.

Comment: That locks the formula on L2 but when I add a new row it will also put the same formula on L3 but it will not calculate the score average for the new person as the range is still D2:K2 and it should be D3:K3.

Comment: All of the other formulas on the table update the range properly except that one but I believe is because the range to calculate the average is on a row and not on a column :(